# Heuristic to sort any "kind" of technical measurements in PHP

Tags: php, measurement

I different lists with measurements of the same dimension but a bit mixed units like

"1 m, 200 mm, 1 ft"

or maybe also

"1 °C, 273 K" and so on.

Now I want to sort them by absolute order

"200 mm, 1 ft, 1 m" and "273 K, 1 °C"

I am wondering if this a an already solved problem, as I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I am afraid, this might be some kind of "shopping for PHP extensions" questions, but I already found some helpful packages:

https://github.com/PhpUnitsOfMeasure/php-units-of-measure can do all kind of conversation between units of measure.

I already have created code to separate unit and number.

So what I am thinking, to "brute force" the unit to a certain dimension of those:

https://github.com/PhpUnitsOfMeasure/php-units-of-measure/tree/master/source/PhysicalQuantity

Next I could pick the first dimension and convert everything to the first "main" SI unit and sort it.

Right?

Comment: Please comment when downvoting, thanks

Comment: Are you saying you only want to sort by the number, ignoring the unit?

Comment: If you already separate unit and number then you could have a map of units and PhpUnitsOfMeasure classes, find the first one there so you know what class to instantiate for each of the unit & number pairs and then compare them.

Comment: @khartnett no, taking the unit into account

Comment: Like you said, sort them according to a common measurement and restore them back to their previous after sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the solution I came up with, based on the suggestions

```
public function testCompareLength()
{
    $this->assertLessThan(0, $this->objectDe->compareFunction('100 mm', '1 m'));
}

public function testCompareTemperature()
{
    $this->assertLessThan(0, $this->objectDe->compareFunction('1 K', '0 °C'));
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $this->objectDe->compareFunction('0 °C', '1 K'));
    $this->assertEquals(0, $this->objectDe->compareFunction('-273 °C', '0 K'));
}
```

---

```
/**
 * @param $numberString
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function parseNumber($numberString): array
{
    $values = preg_split('/(?<=[0-9.,])(?=[^0-9,.]+)/i', $numberString);

    $float = $values[0];
    $unit = $values[1] ?? '';

    $decPos = strpos($float, '.');
    if ($decPos === false) {
        $precision = 0;
    } else {
        $precision = strlen($float) - $decPos - 1;
    }

    return ['float' => $float, 'unit' => $unit, 'precision' => $precision];
}


private function heuristicMeasureFactory($measure)
{
    $prioritizedDimensions = [
        Temperature::class,
        Length::class,
    ];

    $unit = trim($measure['unit']);

    foreach ($prioritizedDimensions as $class) {
        foreach ($class::getUnitDefinitions() as $definition) {
            if ($definition->getName() == $unit) {
                return new $class($measure['float'], $unit);
            }
        }
    }

    // now process aliases
    foreach ($prioritizedDimensions as $class) {
        foreach ($class::getUnitDefinitions() as $definition) {
            foreach ($definition->aliases as $alias) {
                if ($alias == $unit) {
                    return new $class($measure['float'], $unit);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null; // NaN
}

/**
 * Sort apples and oranges -- kind of. Not.
 *
 * Compares two strings which represend a measurement of the same physical dimension
 */
public function compareFunction($a, $b)
{
    $definitions = Temperature::getUnitDefinitions();

    $aParsed = $this->parseNumber($a);
    $aVal = $this->heuristicMeasureFactory($aParsed);

    $bParsed = $this->parseNumber($b);
    $bVal = $this->heuristicMeasureFactory($bParsed);

    if ($aVal == null || $bVal == null) {
        return strnatcmp($aVal, $bVal); // fallback to string comparision
    }

    return bccomp($aVal->subtract($bVal)->toNativeUnit(), 0, 36);
}
```

Comment: The `i` pattern modifier doesn't have any letters to modify in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, what you need to do is convert these units to some common measurement, but only for the purpose of sorting.

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and a custom callback function.  In your callback, do the conversion for the purpose of comparison.

Be sure to keep the original unit when returning the result though, or rounding errors will creep in.